# Laravel 9: change table and fields for authentication and login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-9, laravel-breeze

I have changed the table and the Laravel Breeze fields for authentication to some custom ones. It looks fine but in `AuthenticatedSessionController.php` while I get `Auth::Check() == true`   when it executes `return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);` I get redirected to login page without any error message.

**AuthenticatedSessionController.php**

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerate();
    //Auth::Check() == true here I get true.

    return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

I have only modified `$user->getAuthPassword` to return the new field for password and the `protected $table` variable (and `fillables`) in `user model` to show the new table.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the protected $primaryKey if your custom table primary key is not 'id'. In my case, it redirected me to dashboard when I specify the $primaryKey.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `LoginRequest` Class, you'll see `authenticate()`

there you see this part :

```
if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('username', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
    RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'email' => __('auth.failed'),
    ]);
}
```

Change this :

```
$this->only('username', 'password')
```

To this :

```
[
    'name' => $this->input('username'),
    'password' => $this->input('password'),
]
```

**Actually you just enter DB columns as array keys and Request inputs as values.**